# Is System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add idempotent?

Tags: winforms

In other words, will line 2 in the below code have any effect?

```
// let's assume that myForm has not previously been added  
myControlCollection.Add(myForm);
myControlCollection.Add(myForm); // line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that executing `Add` twice in immediate succession will have no obvious effect. However, if there are intervening `Add` calls with other controls, it will - because `Add` updates the Z-order, sending the newly added control to the back. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        Button b1 = new Button
        {
            Location = new Point(50, 50),
            Size = new Size(40, 40),
            Text = "b1"
        };
        Button b2 = new Button
        {
            Location = new Point(70, 70),
            Size = new Size(40, 40),
            Text = "b2"
        };

        f.Controls.Add(b1);
        f.Controls.Add(b2);
//        f.Controls.Add(b1); 
        Application.Run(f);
    }
}
```

This shows `b1` in front of `b2` - but if you uncomment the second call to `Add(b1)`, the order will be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

No the second line won't have any effect. The collection won't add the same control instance twice.

Answer (score 2):

No effect will be there on execution of second line.