# Windows Forms Application Basics: Keeping all forms in one window

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, forms

I am writing a Windows Forms application in VB.net using Visual Studio 2010 (C# responses are still welcome).

I have created the functionality of my application, and am now working on the UI flow.  Basically, I need to make all of the functionality for the application appear/disappear from the beginning, introductory form.  They click on one of the options in the Introduction.vb form, and the original material disappears and is replaced by whatever they clicked on.  Then, there is a Back button on the next page if they want to go back to the preceding page.  **Here is the original Introduction.vb:**

```vb
Public Class Introduction
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Private Sub Introduction_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

Private Sub AddOrRemoveButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddOrRemoveButton.Click
    AddRemoveCompany.Show() '<-- Show the AddRemoveCompany.vb form when they click on the button.
End Sub

Private Sub InvoiceDocumentButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles InvoiceDocumentButton.Click
    InvoicePrinterAndDocCreator.Show() '<-- .vb form
End Sub 

Private Sub LockOrUnlockButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LockOrUnlockButton.Click
    LockUnlockPIN.Show() '<-- .vb form
End Sub

Private Sub ToExcelButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToExcelButton.Click
    ToExcel.Show() '<-- .vb form
End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, right now I have just simply created a separate form for each area of the application, and linked them off of the main form at the beginning.  The Back buttons on each subsequent form simply close the window.  This all works great, except that the new pages open up in new windows, which I want to avoid.  Instead, I want the new parts to open up in the original window.

From my research, I have found that in order to implement this, I will need to change each of the forms I have created (I foolishly made a Form for each of them) to a UserControl object, and then show or hide the controls appropriately off of the main form.  Problem is, I'm not sure exactly how to do this.  I know how to change my Forms objects to UserControls objects, and fix errors associated with this.

My issues come when I try to develop the logic to Show/Hide the the UserControls off of the main, Introductory page.  I have found results online that suggest I create a Dictionary that contains all of my controls, and then Add/Remove from it as needed.  I have also found results that say I should simply be able to Show/Hide the forms using the logic on my buttons on the main page.  I could not get either one of these methods to work, often encountering an error stating **"top-level control cannot be added to a control."**  Basically, I am stuck, confused, what I try seems to always throw error, and I am wondering what the best way to implement this is.

Let me post (one of) what I have tried that actually works:

```vb
Public Class MainForm
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim x = New Introduction
    Me.Controls.Add(x)
    x.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

This MainForm is of course replacing the old Introduction.vb form, and just showing the Introduction.vb UserControl right off the bat instead.  Here is the new Introduction.vb UserControl:

```vb
Public Class Introduction
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
Private Sub Introduction_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

Private Sub AddOrRemoveButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddOrRemoveButton.Click
    ' Testing logic here:
    Dim y = New AddRemoveCompany '<-- One of my old forms that was converted to a UserControl.
    MainForm.Controls.Clear()
    MainForm.Controls.Add(y)
    y.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub InvoiceDocumentButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles InvoiceDocumentButton.Click
    InvoicePrinterAndDocCreator.Show() '<-- Still works, but still opens in a new window
End Sub

Private Sub LockOrUnlockButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LockOrUnlockButton.Click
    LockUnlockPIN.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub TRSToExcelButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TRSToExcelButton.Click
    TRSToExcel.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

**This method seems sloppy,** although I am at least able to get the next form to display this way without throwing an error.  For example, the back button on that next page is going to basically just Clear out all the old controls and then add in the Introduction.vb UserControl again, and show it again.  Also, what about variable conflicts, now?  I am going to have to make sure all of my variables names are different (correct me if I'm wrong), so for each form I will have to change BackButton to BackButton1, BackButton2, etc.  This method just seems like it will take a lot more time than it is worth and be more confusing to read through.

I would really appreciate if someone took the time to explain a better way to do this, that is not sloppy and is easy to maintain, avoids variable conflicts, is not hard-spaghetti coded together, etc.  Any links to resources online would be appreciated as well, I surprisingly could not find many which went over what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hundreds of ways to do this, one is to set the property TopLevel of your form to false. Or your MainForm should Contain a panel in wich you can load UserControls dynamically.

Basically what you are looking for is a concept called Composite UI. The most Composite UI Applications in .NET Use WPF as is fits better (imho). But there are quite simple concepts for WinForms aswell.(As i mentioned above create a panel and load UserControls dynamically into it).

I must admit i did not read through all of your Text (as it is way to much info for a quite simple question). So i hope i got everything right.

For Example:

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.panelBoarder.Controls.Clear() //Hide old content

            if (this.pageTwo == null)
                this.pageTwo = new PageTwo(); // Create Page Two

            this.panelBoarder.Controls.Add(this.pageTwo);
            this.pageTwo.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Mind going into more detail on this?  I have found this in my research online as well but couldn't get this implemented properly...  I would basically Add/Remove the forms as I did above, but to the MainPanel.Controls collection instead of right on to the MainForm.Controls collection

Comment: What do you wan't to know this is a quite basic task

Comment: Okay, when I create a panel and try to load the various UserControls I created into it, I get the "top-level control cannot be added to a control." error message.  I'm going to try out the same strategy using the above code posted by Steve as a template, since that sets TopLevel to false.  To be honest, I don't know what is meant by "TopLevel", so this is totally due to my misunderstanding of the concepts involved rather than knowing specific code.

Comment: Here is how TopLevel is defined by MSDN: "The top-level control is defined as the parent control that is not parented by another Windows Forms control."  So basically, since the Panel I added to MainForm is not a TopLevel control itself, certainly the UserControls added to it cannot be TopLevel.  And apparently, TopLevel is set to True by default?

Comment: The TopLevel Property is not True on UserControls by default, UserControls do not have a TopLevel Property. Only Forms do have a TopLevel Property. I Suggest you change the type your "Pages" inherit from to UserControl and try it again, or as Steve sugested set the TopLevel Property to false.

Comment: I did change them as recommended and my mistake, you are right they do not have a TopLevel property.  I am still not able to get this working though, I can get my Introduction UserControl to show up on the MainPanel I created on MainForm, BUT then when clicking the buttons on that Introduction UserControl, using the same strategy (as posted in code by Steve), nothing happens/changes.  EDIT:  I am able to get something to change, but only if I do a MainForm.MainPanel.Controls.Clear() beforehand.  Something seems fishy about that but I will continue in this fashion for now.

Comment: I added a example, if you are still stuck please show some code

Comment: I am making very good headway in the last 15 minutes or so, I'm  finally understanding this.  I will post some real code if I need clarification.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are still on SO right now, but I would like to ask you about making the collection for back/forward cycling through a WinForm app.  I tried to add a property to MainForm.vb which is a list of UserControls; I would add a UserControl to the list as I navigate away from the UserControl, and remove it when going Back -- but could not get this to work properly.

Comment: You should create a separate question as this has not much to do with the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58813/discussion-between-console-and-musicode).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example. This assumes your form has a panel on it called Panel1 and the form you want to show in that panel is Form2:

```
Dim f2 As New Form2
f2.TopLevel = False
f2.ControlBox = False
f2.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Panel1.Controls.Add(f2)
f2.Show()
```

You will want to put your previous forms into a collection so you can always go backwards by pulling the last item out of the collection. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm not a fan of modifying the `Controls` collection for a couple of reasons:

- There's a lot of re-drawing that's done unnecessarily (decompile `ControlsCollection.Add` and have a look)
- [You'll mess with the z-order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3369111/251983)
- I've never had a need to do this to accomplish UI related tasks and what you describe above can be done w/o modifying controls

  - Keep it simple :)

[Here's a super bare-bones example of what I think you're asking for.](https://github.com/derfsplat/Breadcrumbs)

It uses `TabPage`'s (without headers) to host the controls (I added labels indicating the "page" but these could just as easily be your user controls).  The back button is handled by a `Stack` since this is what you're looking for- pushing new page selections, and popping them when the user wants to go back:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //...
    Stack<TabPage> breadCrumbs = new Stack<TabPage>();

    private void SwitchTabs(TabPage page)
    {
        breadCrumbs.Push(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = page;
    }

    //...

    //Go back
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(breadCrumbs.Count == 0)
            return;

        var lastTab = breadCrumbs.Pop();
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = lastTab;
    }
}
```

Please note this is a super simple implementation with no concern for, well, separation of concerns. Let me know if you'd like me to go into more detail and I'd be happy to elaborate.